# how to execute java program before deployment

Tags: java, deployment, jetty

I need to execute a java code each time before war file is deployed in `Jetty` server. My need is, each time when I deploy a new war I need to run a java code that clean up my db and add few records before deployment.

I can write this in application startup but its a one time process when deployment takes place.

Can anyone suggest how to do this. Thanks.

Comment: You haven't mentioned what plaform you are targeting. For example if it's Linux you could wrap your WAR as an RPM package. RPM (and other package installers) offers the ability to run scripts pre and post install. It may seem like a lot of effort, but generally pays back thru ease of install and maintenance.

Comment: @MarkO'Connor thanks for your comments Mark. Target is both windows and linux. Typically we use a folder release and replace only WAR file over there whenever changes happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to do this would be to call the code from a ContextListener, but put a flag in the WAR's files in order to execute the code only once when a new WAR file is being deployed.

For example you could put an empty file in your WAR with a certain name, and in the code of your ContextListener, do something like that :

```
if(file is present){
  do something, call DB etc
  delete(file)
}
```

Another (maybe cleaner ?) way would be to put a property in a config properties file with an initial value of false, something like :

```
initialDeploymentCodeExecuted=false
```

Then check for this property instead of a whole file. And change it to true in the code that is executed if it is false.

Comment: Good idea pierre, that was in my mind already. I'm looking for a standard way to do it like add it in deployment life cycle. Take a look [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature/Deployment_Manager).

Comment: Well as far as I know there is no standard JEE way of going this. A "WebappLifecycleListener" or something like that would be useful though. And I am a Tomcat user, so I don't know about any Jetty specific way either. Good luck !

Answer (score 0):

How about a context listener? You can add your db cleanup code in [contextInitialized()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html#contextInitialized%28javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent%29) method.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. ServletContext is for something to initialize each time when application starts. I need one to run one time job when app deployment. Even I can add my code there but take more time time when application startup.

Comment: @vels4j: So you dont want to run it even when application is redeployed?